# Show specific rows first during a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

Basically I have a while loop that lists a bunch of names from my database.

The name table has the name row and a status row...

I can't figure out how to list the names with the status 1 first before it lists the rest of the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database query add an order by on the status field.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to change your DB query

either

```
SELECT name, status
FROM table_name
ORDER BY status ASC
```

or (if you don't want everything ordered)

```
( SELECT name, status
  FROM table_name
  WHERE status = 1
) UNION

( SELECT name, status
  FROM table_name
  WHERE status <> 1
)
```